# Question on iscroll.js for iPad

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, scroll, mobile-safari

How do I customized iscroll.js to have 2-finger scrolling. Below is the URL for the JS library;
http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

I want to simulate the same scrolling for 2-finger (as one gets for 1-finger)...Reason being 1-finger is used for drag action in my case..

Comment: iscroll-5 seems to have 2 finger scrolling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that. iScroll 4 is designed to scroll content on touchstart (1 finger triggers it).

If you want to scroll with 2 fingers, do not use iScroll...

After checking the code of iScroll 4, it is not possible to trigger scroll with 2fingers as it is used to zoom in/out...

You can use native scroll to handle with what you want...

Comment: I mean it cant be customized at all OR if someone could use that code as ref and rewrite for 2-finger...

Comment: It is the same iscroll.js which i want to customize i.e. 1-finger scroll which it offers to a 2-finger scroll...